# Apache - tomcat server communication

Tags: apache, web-services, rest, tomcat, webserver

I'm creating a web application using javaScript and backbone and hosted in an apache server. The backend connection(tomcat server) is specified in the apache2 sites-enabled folder(ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse) . Its works fine but some certain custom error codes from tomcat server are not get back to apache. If we connect the application directly with tomcat, there is no problem but, here a 404 received instead of the custom error code.

> For example- we create an error code **76** for **NO_RECORD_FOUND_ERROR**, but
>   while doing this setting I got an error code **404** instead of **76**. If I
>   connected directly to tomcat server, it'll get **76** correctly.

Please feel free to reply to this, it would be a great help for me

thanks 
Jyothis

Comment: How are you trying to return these "error codes"? Are you trying to use HTTP status codes for this purpose? I haven't read the full HTTP spec, but it's possible that a 2-digit response code is not legal, and Apache httpd is overriding it because of that. Maybe try to use a response header for your application-specific error codes instead of using the HTTP response code?